# How to automate the process of acquiring NASDAQ historical stock prices?

Tags: javascript, ajax, postman, web-inspector, stockquotes

I'm trying to get the raw data for 10 year historical daily prices for 200+ different tickers via https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/aapl/historical. What I'm doing now is searching for each ticker, selecting '10 years' from the Timeframe drop down menu, waiting for the response, and then clicking 'Download this file in Excel Format' at the bottom corner.

Obviously this is very tedious and time consuming so I'm trying to see if there is there is any way to automate this.

I noticed the 'Download this file in Excel Format' button calls a JS function:

```
function getQuotes(download) {
        if (!download)
            showLoadingSpinner();

        var data = $("[id$='ddlTimeFrame']").val();
        var submitString = data + '|' + download + "|" + quoteBoxSelectedSymbol; if (!download) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: baseUrl,
                data: submitString,
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (response) {
                    $("[id$='historicalContainer']").html(response);
                    $(".genTable tbody tr:odd").addClass("genTablealt");
                    hideLoadingSpinner();
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            $("[id$='submitString']").val(submitString);
            $("#getFile").submit();
        }
    }
```

The download variable seems to be a boolean that is passed as true when the button is hit. Is there maybe a way to inject whatever endpoint that function is generating to something like Postman? I am not very familiar with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

you'll need at least 2 requests

```
    1. GET request:    to get the required cookies
    2. POST request:   to change timespan/
                       -> parse response / downlaod excel
```

### **1 - initial get request [set_cookie]**

```
    GET /symbol/aapl/historical HTTP/1.1
    Host: www.nasdaq.com
    cache-control: no-cache
```

**Tests**

```
pm.test("valid response", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
    pm.response.to.be.withBody;
    pm.expect(pm.response.text()).to.include("Results for: ");
});
```

*the following is only needed when downloading excel*

```
// ... continue test code ...
var input = pm.response.text();
var regex = /"__VIEWSTATE" value="(.*?)"/;
var match = regex.exec(input);
if (match) pm.globals.set("__VIEWSTATE", match[1]);  
var regex = /"__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="(.*?)"/;
var match = regex.exec(input);
if (match) pm.globals.set("__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR", match[1]);  
var regex = /"__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED" value="(.*?)"/;
var match = regex.exec(input);
if (match) pm.globals.set("__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED", match[1]);  
var regex = /"__EVENTVALIDATION" value="(.*?)"/;
var match = regex.exec(input);
if (match) pm.globals.set("__EVENTVALIDATION", match[1]);
//-----
var regex = /<option value="(\d+[dmy])">10 Years<\/option>/;
var match = regex.exec(input);
if (match) var timeframe = match[1];
pm.globals.set("timeframe", timeframe);
//-----
var regex = /var quoteBoxSelectedSymbol="(.*?)";/;
var match = regex.exec(input);
if (match) var symbol = match[1];
pm.globals.set("symbol", symbol);
//-----
var submitNoDownload = timeframe + "|false|" + symbol;
pm.globals.set("submitNoDownload", submitNoDownload);
var submitToDownload = timeframe + "|true|" + symbol;
pm.globals.set("submitToDownload", submitToDownload);
```

### **2 - get data directly from page; no download**

```
    POST /symbol/aapl/historical HTTP/1.1
    Host: www.nasdaq.com
    x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest
    content-type: application/json
    accept: */*
    cache-control: no-cache

    {{submitNoDownload}}
```

**Tests**

```
pm.test("valid response", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
    pm.response.to.be.withBody;
    pm.expect(pm.response.text()).to.include("Results for: ");
});

var input = pm.response.text();
var regex = /<tr>\s+(?:<td>\s+(\S+)\s+<\/td>\s+)(?:<td>\s+(\S+)\s+<\/td>\s+)(?:<td>\s+(\S+)\s+<\/td>\s+)(?:<td>\s+(\S+)\s+<\/td>\s+)(?:<td>\s+(\S+)\s+<\/td>\s+)(?:<td>\s+(\S+)\s+<\/td>\s+)<\/tr>/mg;
var match = regex.exec(input);
while (match != null) {
    // Iterate thru all rows/data
    pm.globals.set("date", match[1]);  
    pm.globals.set("open", match[2]);  
    pm.globals.set("high", match[3]);  
    pm.globals.set("low", match[4]);   
    pm.globals.set("close-last", match[5]);   
    pm.globals.set("volume", match[6]);  
    match = regex.exec(input);
}
```

### **3 - download excel**

*First things first! What do we have here..*

```
var data = $("[id$='ddlTimeFrame']").val();
var submitString = data + '|' + download + "|" + quoteBoxSelectedSymbol;
```

1. $(...)               = (jquery) current document
2. [id$='ddlTimeFrame'] = select/returns a html-element with id = "ddlTimeFrame" (see below)
3. .val()               = get the value of the selected html element

*the above code will select the following html code*

```
<select id="ddlTimeFrame" name="ddlTimeFrame" onchange="getQuotes(false)">
    <option value="5d">5 Days</option>
    <option value="1m">1 Month</option>
    <option value="3m" selected="selected">3 Months</option>
    <option value="6m">6 Months</option>
    <option value="1y">1 Year</option>
    <option value="18m">18 Months</option>
    <option value="2y">2 Years</option>
    <option value="3y">3 Years</option>
    <option value="4y">4 Years</option>
    <option value="5y">5 Years</option>
    <option value="6y">6 Years</option>
    <option value="7y">7 Years</option>
    <option value="8y">8 Years</option>
    <option value="9y">9 Years</option>
    <option value="10y">10 Years</option>
</select>
```

*somewhere in the html code*

```
var quoteBoxSelectedSymbol="AAPL";
```

1. data                   = 10y
2. download               = true
3. quoteBoxSelectedSymbol = AAPL
4. submitString           = 10y|true|AAPL

```
    POST /symbol/aapl/historical HTTP/1.1
    Host: www.nasdaq.com
    x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
    cache-control: no-cache

    __VIEWSTATE:{{__VIEWSTATE}}
    __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR:{{__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR}}
    __VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED:{{__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED}}
    __EVENTVALIDATION:{{__EVENTVALIDATION}}
    ctl00$quotes_content_left$submitString:{{submitToDownload}}
```

Comment: postman example
https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/7240986/SVSGNqPX